# How to set Calender to Particular date and time in java

Tags: java, time, calendar

I am using Calender class of java ..Here calender has been set for day of week and time .Now as per my need i want to set it for date of month and time like calender should be set for 10th of month and time time should be 10 a.m..But i am not able to get it ..

Here is my code..

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.set(
            Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
            Calendar.TUESDAY);
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Please help me..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i want to set date for particular date here it is set for week and week day name ..

Comment: Use JodaTime http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html

Comment: Regarding Joda-Time, the team now advises migration to java.time classes. Project is in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want set the date of the month, then you could use either of the two, interchangeably.

```
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10); // Synonym of DATE
date.set(Calendar.DATE, 10); // Synonym of DAY_OF_MONTH
```

Comment: How to set a time period in Calendar instance...like from 1st of july to 5th of july?

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal : Here you go, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR

Answer (score 4):

Your code works, only difference is your setting day. but which week of the day?

below code to demonstrate to to set date and time to calender.

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    long today = date.getTimeInMillis();
    date.set(
            Calendar.DATE,11);
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    date.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
    date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    long lastday = date.getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println(date.getTimeInMillis());

    long diff = today - lastday;
    diff = ((diff/1000)/360);
    System.out.println("Hours diff :"+diff);
```

Comment: Instead of recommending `date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);` I would recommend `date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);` since it's probably much more likely to give users a good experience.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of( 2016 , 9 , 10 , 10 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) )
```

## Details

The accepted [answer by Ɍ.Ɉ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19921812/642706) is correct.

## java.time

Here is the way to do the same but with modern java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

The http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html class represents a moment on the timeline in a particular time zone with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Instantiate with all the specific year, month, hour, etc. arguments: [`of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond, ZoneId zone)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-java.time.ZoneId-).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2016 , 9 , 10 , 10 , 0 , 0 , 0 , z );
```

See a String representation of that value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format extended by appending name of time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString();
```

> 2016-09-10T10:00:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]

If you want Strings generated in other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter`.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.